# simple SAS select into

Tags: sql, sas, sas-macro

I want to use "select into" to create a list of all IDs in SAS.

```
/* my state table try01 */   
data try01;  
input id  state $;  
cards;  
1108 va  
1102 dc  
1101 md  
1105 on  
;  

run;

/* select into */   
proc sql noprint;   
select id into: x from try01;   
quit;

%put &x;
```

My question is why the log shows that macro x is only one value (1108) instead 
of a list (1108,1102,1101,1105) ? So confused... thanks a lot.

Comment: `into` puts the value into a scalar variable.  Why would you expect a list?

Comment: because the result of sql clause select id returns a list (1108,1102,1101,1105) . so macro x should be a list too. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 3):

If you want SQL to put multiple values into the macro variable then you need to include the `SEPARATED BY` clause.

```
select id into :x separated by ' ' from try01;
```

You could then use this list in, for example an `IN` operator call.

```
proc print data=have ;
   where id in (&x);
run;
```